# How to do pattern matching in python lists?

Tags: python, arrays, pattern-matching

I have been trying to code a function that if given a 2d array like

```
[
  ["1", "n", "1"], 
  ["n", "0", "n"], 
  ["n", "n", "n"]
]
```

would return those arrays from a set of arrays which have 1 on [0][0] and [0][2] index and 0 on [2][2] index . So I came up with this code

```py
variations = []
for i in range(0, 512):
    subarr1 = list(bin((i // 64))[2:].zfill(3))
    subarr2 = list(bin(((i - ((i // 64) * 64)) // 8))[2:].zfill(3))
    subarr3 = list(bin((i - ((i // 8) * 8)))[2:].zfill(3))
    arr = [subarr1, subarr2, subarr3]
    variations.append(arr)

pbvariations = [[['0','0','0'],['0','0','0'],['0','0','0']],[['1', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0']]]
# copy.deepcopy(variations)


def findvariation(gamearr):
    global pbvariations
    for i in range(len(gamearr)):
        for j in range(3):
            if gamearr[i][j] == "n":
                continue
            elif gamearr[i][j] == "1":
                for k in pbvariations:
                    if k[i][j] != "1":
                        pbvariations.remove(k)
            else:
                for k in pbvariations:
                    if k[i][j] != "0":
                      pbvariations.remove(k)


sample = [["1", "n", "1"], ["n", "0", "n"], ["n", "n", "n"]]
findvariation(sample)
print(pbvariations)
```

This code works perfectly but when I change pbvariations to copy.deepcopy(variations) it does not work at all and returns [['0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0'], ['0', '1', '1']] for the first element of pbvariations. I have been trying for hours but can't get it. Even if I change the value of pbvariations to [[['0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0'], ['0', '1', '1']]]  it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
variations = []
for i in range(512):
    subarr1 = list(bin((i // 64))[2:].zfill(3))
    subarr2 = list(bin(((i - ((i // 64) * 64)) // 8))[2:].zfill(3))
    subarr3 = list(bin((i - ((i // 8) * 8)))[2:].zfill(3))
    arr = [subarr1, subarr2, subarr3]
    variations.append(arr)

def find_variations(P_variations, P_sample):
    for x in range(len(P_variations)): # iter through the variations
        found = True 
        for y in range(3):
            if not found: break
            for z in range(3):
                if P_sample[y][z] not in ["n",P_variations[x][y][z]]: # if the item isn't "n" nor matches the corresponding item in the sample...
                    # move on to the next iter of variations
                    found = False
                    break
        if found: return P_variations[x] # if the case matches the sample, return it

print(find_variations(variations,[["1", "n", "1"], ["n", "0", "n"], ["n", "n", "n"]])) # [['1', '0', '1'], ['0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0']]
```

All this is doing is going through every item in the variations and comparing them against the sample. If the item is not an "n" and doesn't match the respective sample item, leave it alone. If it does match, return it.
It's certainly not the most compact system ever. You are welcome to change anything (such as the `P_` at the start of the parameters; this is just to signify what's a param and what's not), or make it so that it returns every single matching item, which you can do by replacing the `return variations[x]` with `results.append(variations[x])` and then returning results at the end of the function (of course, you would need to initialise `results` beforehand).

Comment: Thank you so much , would you mind explaining why we have ```if not found: break``` in starting , what do you think was missing in my approach. again thanks

Comment: @MOHDSAAD the `if not found: break`part is to properly **backtrack** through the loops in order to skip straight to the next item. without it, the code would simply move onto another part of the **same item**. the double-break is necessary to properly skip to the next item.